# Gradle Jacoco Plugin: Generate coverage from classes in another module

Tags: java, android, gradle, jacoco

I am working on a library project that contains two modules: the main module contains the logic, and I have a test module that contains a couple of test utils related from the main module classes, as well tests from main module. I needed to move tests to the test module to avoid a circular dependency. Ok.

Now, I need to generate the coverage of the core module, after running the tests (contained into test module). My `jacoco` configuration is something like this:

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest') {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    jacocoClasspath = configurations['androidJacocoAnt']

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${rootProject.projectDir}/test-module/build/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def debugMainTree = fileTree(dir: "${rootProject.projectDir}/main-module/build/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${rootProject.projectDir}/test-module/src/main/java"
    def mainMainSrc = "${rootProject.projectDir}/main-module/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    additionalSourceDirs = files([mainMainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    additionalClassDirs = files([debugMainTree])
    executionData = files "${buildDir}/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
}
```

All classes is appearing in the report, but with 0% coverage. I am receiving some warning on output, saying things like:

```
[ant:jacocoReport] Classes in bundle 'test-module' do no match with execution data. For report generation the same class files must be used as at runtime.
[ant:jacocoReport] Execution data for class my/class/from/MainModule does not match.
```

I took a look on `intermediates` folders, trying to figure out from where the tests takes the main class files, but had no success.

BTW, this is an Android Library project (with 2 artifacts that are published internally). I am using Gradle 2.8.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I have a simillar problem in a multimodule gradle project.